# Maketitle tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to to get the same output as `\maketitle` in a `tikzpicture` so that I can adjust it and draw behind it. Here's some basic test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fontsize{80}{0}\selectfont
    \coordinate (cen) at (current page.center);
    \node at (cen) {some big text};
    \node at ($(cen)-(0,2)$) {lower text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\setcounter{page}0
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

How do I make it the same as `\maketitle`?

Comment: You can draw behind `\maketitle` by adding the tikz picture to the background. Which other modifications do plan to do?

Comment: (an easy way to add the tikz picture to the background is to surround it with `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{...}`)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, but I want to modify the positions, font, and size.

Comment: In this case, it sounds like a waste of time to first recreate the exact output of maketitle. Why not directly ask for the layout you'd like to have?

Comment: How am I supposed to know that? I can make my own, after having a base layout.